# Issues when create a Meteor Package Wrapper for Libraries

Tags: meteor, npm

I am trying to make a meteor package wrapper for the switchery (https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) library. I followed the "official guide" as far as I understand.

So I made a fork (https://github.com/mediatainment/switchery) of the original, created a meteor folder in the root of the fork and started to add some basic stuff to get it working:

Filestructure

`root
 | 
 |-meteor
 |   |-export.js
 |   |-tests.js
 |-package.js // I found out that this must be in root
 |-package.json // added devDependencies for my Package
 |-switchery.js
 |-switchery.css`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "switchery",
  "version": "0.7.0",
  "description": "Create iOS 7 styled switches from default input checkboxes",
  "main": "switchery.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/abpetkov/switchery.git"
  },
  "author": "Alexander Petkov",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.8",
    "component": "^1.0.0",
    "uglifycss": "0.0.7",
    "grunt-exec": "latest",
    "spacejam": "latest",
    "jasmine-node": "latest",
    "coffee-script": "latest"
  }
}
```

package.js

```
// package metadata file for Meteor.js
'use strict';

var packageName = 'mediatainment:switchery'; // https://atmospherejs.com/mediatainment/switchery
var where = 'client'; // where to install: 'client' or 'server'. For both, pass nothing.

var packageJson = JSON.parse(Npm.require("fs").readFileSync('package.json'));

Package.describe({
    name: packageName,
    summary: 'Switchery (official) - turns your default HTML checkbox inputs into beautiful iOS 7 style switches in just few simple steps. Easy customizable to fit your design perfectly.',
    version: "0.0.1", //packageJson.version,
    git: 'https://github.com/mediatainment/switchery'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom(['METEOR@0.9.0', 'METEOR@1.0']);
    api.export('Switchery');
    api.addFiles(['switchery.js', 'switchery.css', 'meteor/export.js'], where);
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
    api.use(packageName, where);
    api.use('tinytest', where);
    api.addFiles('meteor/tests.js', where); // testing specific files
});
```

meteor/export.js

```
/*global Switchery:true*/ // Meteor creates a file-scope global for exporting. This comment prevents a potential JSHint warning.
Switchery= window.Switchery;
delete window.Switchery;
```

Looks quite straight forward, but I have the following errors:

• when I add my local package to an empty Project this results in

```
While reading package from `/Users/jan/WebstormProjects/packages/switchery`:
fs.js:438:18: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'package.json'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
at package.js:7:48
```

When I hardcode the VersionNumber eg: "0.0.1" and remove the

```
var packageJson = JSON.parse(Npm.require("fs").readFileSync('package.json'));
```

this error is gone and I can start the app, but
• new errors appear in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
switchery.js:18 (anonymous function)
mediatainment_switchery.js (anonymous function) mediatainment_switchery.js? (anonymous function)
global-imports.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Switchery' of undefinedglobal-imports.js (anonymous function)
template.ptest.js Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not definedtemplate.ptest.js(anonymous function)
template.ptest.js (anonymous function)
ptest.js Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
ptest.js (anonymous function)
ptest.js (anonymous function) application.js:23 No valid media id detected`

The Library to include in my Package is simply a css and js file.

What I am doing wrong? (Meteor 1.0.3.1)

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IMO, You are doing it in wrong. 
Basically, you are forking original repo of the lib and making changes there onwards for porting into meteor (basically making Meteor package).

Consider the situation, where original lib repo (upstream) gets updated but you already published the package in Atomosphere and now you want get updated code of the upstream in your Meteor, might you not able to merge in sometime in later (may be due to ).

So, common approach while integrating external library as Meteor package, is you keep original lib repo (upstream) as the **git submodule** of your Meteor package repo.

Like

```
meteor-switchery
- lib
-- <original-lib-repo-git-submodule>
-package.js
-package.json
```

You can refer to following package which are integrated as the meteor package for external js libraries, which follows approach i mentioned above

[Meteor bootstrap tagsinput](https://github.com/ajduke/meteor-bootstrap-tagsinput)

[Meteor Bootstrap TokenField](https://github.com/ajduke/meteor-boostrap-tokenfield)

And you are putting same version as original library with version mentioned in package.json. **Please do not this**

Put it as separate versions itself. By maintaining different versions, it gives flexibility to change version while putting new version of original library or some fixes or if upgraded some of dependency etc

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was also my first thought. But then I've done the "official Package implementation" from the MeteorCommunity https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/14 . In the meantime I have found out what I am doing wrong. I was using the ```root``` files instead of the ```/dist``` files.

Comment: okay cool, didn't know that this kind of efforts are going for meteor package portability into official repo only

Answer (score 0):

My issue was, that I was using the `root` files of the external libraries instead of them in the `/dist` folder. So this is the correct way:

`api.addFiles(['dist/switchery.js', 'dist/switchery.css', 'meteor/export.js'], where);`